# Cleaning up dataset where each record is treated as a table

Tags: python, pandas, datatables, data-cleaning

I have a dataset of close to 800k rows. There should only be about 6k distinct records with multiple columns of data. The issue is each record is treated as a table. For example:

```
header            data

id                     238
name           machine_one
serial             1234556
purchase_date   11/19/2010
status                good
id                     239
name           machine_two
serial             3456789
purchase_date   11/19/2020
status                 bad
id                     240
name           machine_six
serial             1122334
purchase_date   11/19/2019
status                fair
```

NOTE: each record contains a different number of data points. I am using five as an example, but some have 30, some 12, and so on. Before each new record there is a "NEWRECORD ****" row that denotes a new entry.

I have cleaned it up some, it was all one string with no structure. Would a crosstab be what I'm looking for? Any pointers/hints greatly appreciated.

Comment: What format is this data in? Is it a list of lists? ndarray? Dataframe?

Comment: @thehumaneraser it's a dataframe

Answer (score 0):

given above data:

```
import pandas as pd

data=[{'header': 'id', 'data': '238'},
 {'header': 'name', 'data': 'machine_one'},
 {'header': 'serial', 'data': '1234556'},
 {'header': 'purchase_date', 'data': '11/19/2010'},
 {'header': 'status', 'data': 'good'},
 {'header': 'id', 'data': '239'},
 {'header': 'name', 'data': 'machine_two'},
 {'header': 'serial', 'data': '3456789'},
 {'header': 'purchase_date', 'data': '11/19/2020'},
 {'header': 'status', 'data': 'bad'},
 {'header': 'id', 'data': '240'},
 {'header': 'name', 'data': 'machine_six'},
 {'header': 'serial', 'data': '1122334'},
 {'header': 'purchase_date', 'data': '11/19/2019'},
 {'header': 'status', 'data': 'fair'}]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

can you assume that each record is 5 lines?  if yes, then you can do this:

```
## create record index column
record = pd.DataFrame(pd.Series(range(len(df)//5)).repeat(5)).reset_index(drop=True)

## concatenate it horizontally to your file:
df = pd.concat([df, record], axis=1).rename(columns={0:'record'})

### pivot the result and cleanup index headings:
df = df.pivot(columns='header', index='record').copy().reset_index(drop=True)
df.columns = df.columns.get_level_values(1)
df.columns.name = None

print(df)
```

OUTPUT:

```
    id  name    purchase_date   serial  status
0   238 machine_one 11/19/2010  1234556 good
1   239 machine_two 11/19/2020  3456789 bad
2   240 machine_six 11/19/2019  1122334 fair
```

Comment: They all have a different number of lines, but there is a row called NEWRECORD **** each time the new record starts. So I'd have to restart the index there. Would it be the same steps minus the `len` ? Do I need to escape the * ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  if your data is different from what you shared in the question you have to specify that.  the logic here assumes your data comes in with 5 rows per one record, so it converts 5 lines to one record.

Comment: I should have been more specific, I've edited my question. Each record has a different number of data points-- some have 5, others 12, etc.